# C++ object's type definition comparison, ignoring the wrong one with compiler

Tags: c++, macros, type-deduction

I need an if-else comparison that will ask if the object in it is of a certain type. I will also need the compiler to ignore the wrong line.

So it will be something like

```
#if (/* the object is an objectType */)
    object.doSmth();
#else
    object.doSmthElse();
#endif
```

I had something like

```
strcmp(typeid(object).name(), "class objectType")==0
```

but only the #else line works then.

I'm confused with the comparison part. Is there a normal way to define it at all?

Comment: I think what you need is either a better inheritance structure, or a specialized template function.

Comment: `#if` is a preprocessor directive. Did you mean `if`?

Comment: @molbdnilo no, since I need compiler to ignore the unused line. In my case non-objectType object doesn't have the `doSmth()` function, so it will not be compiled using a simple if.

Comment: @MariaDmitrievich You can't do anything like that with the preprocessor, as preprocessing happens even before parsing. You need some kind of dynamic dispatching on the type at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can distinguish between types using function templates and overloads:

```
void doSmth(objectType & object) {object.doSmth();}
template <class Type> void doSmth(Type & object) {object.doSmthElse();}
```

Now `doSmth(object)` will select the first if `object` is has type `objectType` and the second otherwise, as specified by your pseudocode.